# Find rapid increase events from below to above threshold in timeseries

Tags: r, dplyr

Hi I'm trying to set up a function to find events where a timeseries goes from below a lower threshold to above a higher one in a certain amount of time steps but I feel like there should be a more elegant solution and I'm not 100% confident I've captured all cases

Example Data

```
df <- data.frame(DateTime = seq.POSIXt(from = as.POSIXct("2019-01-01"),to = as.POSIXct("2019-01-02"), by ="hour"),
           Value = c(1,9,150,9,150,120,110,50,60,50,50,5,5,7,5,110,110,40,110,2,8,120,5,130,120))
```

> Here is the basic logic. For a minThresh and maxThresh (lets say 10 and 100) and window size (here 4 given in `slide`) I want to say this point is a peak (output = 1) if all of the below:

- This value (the last in the window) is above maxThresh
- One of the values within the window are below the minThresh
- Since the last minThresh no other value is above the maxThresh (so if the values in the window are (7,5,110,110) this point will NOT be a peak as the previous value will have been assigned as one)

Here is what I have so far

```
library(dplyr)
library(tsibble)

myfun <- function(dat, minThresh=10, maxThresh=100){
  thisVal <- dat[length(dat)]

  #Check this value > max threshold
  if(!thisVal > maxThresh) return(0)

  #Check there is a value less than min threshold
  belowThreshol <- which(dat<minThresh)
  if(length(belowThreshol)==0) return(0)

  #reset values after going above max and below min (so first peak doesn't stop 2nd peak counting)
  # eg for case (dat = c(1,500,2,500)) resets at 2
  aboveThreshol <- (dat>maxThresh)
  aboveThreshol[1:max(belowThreshol)] <- FALSE

  #check that thisValue is the first (after reset) > maxThresh
  if(min(which(aboveThreshol)) < length(dat)) return(0)

return(1)
}

df %>% mutate(test = slide_dbl(Value, myfun, .size = 4))
```

I would prefer, if possible, a tidyverse solution

Comment: If I apply your function, the output I have has row 5 which has Value as 150 has 1. How can that be 1 as row 3 also has 150 which comes in its sliding window size of 4?

Comment: @RonakShah if the value falls below the minThresh within the sliding window of four then it is reset, so for example if you have `c(9,150,9,150)` this will output 1 at both 150s as they are two individual peaks

Comment: added an answer. See if it works for your case.

Answer (score 0):

```
slide = 4
minThresh = 10
maxThresh = 100
```

My version using `rollapply` from `zoo`

```
myfun <- function(x) {
  min_ind <- which(x < minThresh)
  if ((x[length(x)] > maxThresh) & (length(min_ind) > 0)) #condition 1 & condition 2
    if(sum(x[max(min_ind):length(x)] > maxThresh) == 1) #condition 3
        return(1)
  return(0)
}
```

and now apply this function using a sliding window of size `slide`

```
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(test = lag(rollapply(Value,slide,myfun,fill = NA, align = "left"),slide-1))


#              DateTime Value test
#1  2019-01-01 00:00:00     1   NA
#2  2019-01-01 01:00:00     9   NA
#3  2019-01-01 02:00:00   150   NA
#4  2019-01-01 03:00:00     9    0
#5  2019-01-01 04:00:00   150    1
#6  2019-01-01 05:00:00   120    0
#7  2019-01-01 06:00:00   110    0
#8  2019-01-01 07:00:00    50    0
#9  2019-01-01 08:00:00    60    0
#10 2019-01-01 09:00:00    50    0
#11 2019-01-01 10:00:00    50    0
#12 2019-01-01 11:00:00     5    0
#13 2019-01-01 12:00:00     5    0
#14 2019-01-01 13:00:00     7    0
#15 2019-01-01 14:00:00     5    0
#16 2019-01-01 15:00:00   110    1
#17 2019-01-01 16:00:00   110    0
#18 2019-01-01 17:00:00    40    0
#19 2019-01-01 18:00:00   110    0
#20 2019-01-01 19:00:00     2    0
#21 2019-01-01 20:00:00     8    0
#22 2019-01-01 21:00:00   120    1
#23 2019-01-01 22:00:00     5    0
#24 2019-01-01 23:00:00   130    1
#25 2019-01-02 00:00:00   120    0
```

We have used `lag` here because when input is `c(5, 7, 5, 110)` the output is returned as 1 but it gets assigned to the first 5 in the sequence whereas we need output to be 1 for 110 so for that we need to shift the 1 with respect to the window size.